# How to bind an ObservableCollection<bool> to a Listbox of Checkboxes in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Let me prefix this question by stating that I'm very new to both C# and WPF.

I'm trying to connect a collection of `Boolean` values to a container containing 6 checkboxes, and have the state of these values stored when a button is pressed. I'm assuming there is an easy way to do this, since binding checkboxes to a collection of seems a very natural thing to do, but all the solutions I have seen so far have seemed overly complicated (example: http://merill.net/2009/10/wpf-checked-listbox/).

I create the checkboxes by modifying the data template of a `ListBox` and set the `ItemsSource` of the `ListBox` to the `ObservableCollection`, but my problem is that I don't know what to bind the `IsChecked` to, since I'm trying to bind it to the actual object in the collection and not a property of the object.

Comment: Could you please add your code so we can help you better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `IsChecked="{Binding}"` to bind the item of the collection directly.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyBooleanCollection}" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

However it is not possible to do bind to source with this method. Because the binding on the `IsChecked` property of the `CheckBox` doesn't the index of the item of the binding. So, it can't change the collection but only the item of the collection.

### Update

To get around that limitation, you can create a wrapper to the Boolean value:

```
public class Wrapper<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private T value;
    public T Value
    {
        get { return value; }
        set
        {
            {
                this.value = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public static implicit operator Wrapper<T>(T value)
    {
        return new Wrapper<T> { value = value };
    }
    public static implicit operator T(Wrapper<T> wrapper)
    {
        return wrapper.value;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Here is an exemple of usage:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Wrapper<bool>> MyBooleanCollection { get; private set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = this;
        MyBooleanCollection = new ObservableCollection<Wrapper<bool>>() { false, true, true, false, true };
    }
}
```

And in the XAML:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Value}"/>
```

Comment: This requires setting `Mode="OneWay"` when you bind to e.g. a `List<bool>`.

Comment: Thank you! I wish I could give you reputation but I just created this account.

Answer (score 4):

In the `ItemTemplate` you may write

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=.}"/>
```

or

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Mode=OwnWay}"/>
```

which binds directly to the item object, i.e. the `bool` value from the collection.

---

Note however that in either case the bound values in the collection will not be replaced when a CheckBox is checked or unchecked. In order to immediately update the collection when a CheckBox is clicked, your collection would have to contain objects with a boolean property to which `IsChecked` is bound.

In your case this could be as simple as the following (as your question sounds like you don't need property change notifications):

```
public class BooleanHelper
{
    public bool Value { get; set; }
}
```

The binding would now look like this:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Value}"/>
```

The collection would now be an `ObservableCollection<BooleanHelper>` and you would perhaps add items like this:

```
Items.Add(new BooleanHelper { Value = true });
```

Comment: What is the purpose of writing `Path=.`? This only removes the error for two-way binding and binding to source but does not fix the problem (just hides it). It's safer to write `{Binding}`.

Comment: @CédricBignon Actually I haven't said that this is *better* than writing `{Binding Mode=OneWay}`. It doesn't matter, as OP will have to put objects with a boolean property in his collection anyway, just as you've shown in your answer.

Comment: OK, but I say that's worse. Because you don't see it is one-way.

Answer (score 0):

By the link that you provided, you could also use INotifyPropertyChanged extension to your CheckedListItem class, but thats if you dont want use ObservableCollection. It would be something like this:

```
public class CheckedListItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _Id;
    public int Id 
    {
        get;
        set; NotifyIfAnythingChanged("Id");
    }

    private string _Name;
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set; NotifyIfAnythingChanged("Name");
    }

    private bool _IsChecked;
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get;
        set; NotifyIfAnythingChanged("IsChecked");
    }

    private void NotifyIfAnythingChanged(String propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Your listbox should be something like this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="MyListBox">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content={Binding Path=Name} IsChecked="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsChecked}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

In your code behind you should initialize the ObservableCollection just once, because every change made into it will result into an UI update.

```
ObservableCollection<CheckedListItem> MyList = new ObservableCollection<CheckedListItem>();
MyListBox.ItemsSource = MyList;
```

Now every change made into MyList, such as Add(), Remove(), Etc. Will affect your UI.