# Binding an ObservableCollection<int> that holds indexes to a ListBox of CheckBoxes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

In my C# / WPF / .NET 4.5 project, I have an `ObservableCollection<int>` which holds indexes. I also have a `ListBox` with its `ItemsPanelTemplate` set to a `UniformGrid` (with 20 rows and 20 columns) and its `ItemTemplate` set as a `CheckBox`es.

I want the `ObservableCollection<int>` to hold the indexes of the `CheckBoxes` that are checked. This should be accomplished via a `TwoWay` binding: When an `int` is added or removed from the `ObservableCollection`, `CheckBoxes` in the `UniformGrid` should become checked or unchecked; and when I check or uncheck a `CheckBox`, its index should be added to or removed from the `ObservableCollection`.

I tried to accomplish this using a converter in the following manner:

**XAML:**

```
<ListBox
    x:Name="myListBox"
    SelectionMode="Multiple"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Cells, Converter={StaticResource cellsConverter}}">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="20" Columns="20"></UniformGrid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

**The class that contains the `ObservableCollection<int>`:**

```
public class Frame : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    private ObservableCollection<int> _cells;

    public ObservableCollection<int> Cells {
      get { return _cells; }
      set {
        _cells = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Cells");
      }
    }

    public Frame() {
      Cells = new ObservableCollection<int>();
    }

    // Event handler for INotifyPropertyChanged 
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void OnPropertyChanged(string propName) {
      if (PropertyChanged != null) {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
      }
    }
  }
```

**Converter:**

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(ObservableCollection<int>), typeof(ObservableCollection<bool>))]
public class CellsConverter : IValueConverter {

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        ObservableCollection<int> ints = (ObservableCollection<int>)value;
        ObservableCollection<bool> bools = new ObservableCollection<bool> ();

        for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++) {
            bool b = new bool();
            if (ints.Contains(i)) b = true;
            else b = false;
            bools.Add(b);
        }

       return bools;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        ObservableCollection<bool> bools = (ObservableCollection<bool>)value;
        ObservableCollection<int> ints = new ObservableCollection<int>();

        foreach (bool b in bools) {
            if (b == true) ints.Add(bools.IndexOf(b));
        }

       return ints;
    }
}
```

This is possibly not ideal method for accomplishing this, and in that case I would appreciate if anyone proposes a different method.

When I run this, I get a `XamlParseException` saying that "Two-way binding requires Path or XPath." I guess the issue is similar to [the one posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17810092/how-to-bind-an-observablecollectionbool-to-a-listbox-of-checkboxes-in-wpf), but I could not figure out how to apply the solutions there to my case where I'm using a converter.

Questions:

- Is this a good way of binding a collection of indexes to a `ListBox`?
- If it is, how can I correct my implementation?
- If not, what would be a better way?

**EDIT**

For clarity, an illustration of what I want to achieve:

```
ParentOfMyListBox.DataContext = new Frame();
```

The appearance of myListBox:

[image]

```
indexes.Add(0);
indexes.Add(3);
```

[image]

```
indexes.Remove(0);
```

[image]

Then if I manually check one of the cells...

[image]

Now `indexes` contains `3` and `8`.

Comment: without referring back to your existing code, can you please clarify what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

Remember, KISS - Keep it simple, stupid.

1) Create a wrapper class, that holds:

- IsChecked boolean property
- Value integer property

In XAML, bind against IsChecked property:

```
<ListBox
    SelectionMode="Multiple"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Cells}">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="20" Columns="20"></UniformGrid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Now, if you need to get ObservableCollection; you can use simple LINQ query:

```
new ObservableCollection<int>(Cells.Where(x= x.IsChecked).Select(x => x.Value));
```

The converter hack that shouldn't be used, but can give you ideas to implement it without one:

```
private void UpdateUnderlyingCollection(
    ObservableCollection<int> underlyingCollection , 
    int element, 
    bool isChecked)
{
    if (!isChecked)
        underlyingCollection.Remove(element);
    else if(!underlyingCollection.Contains(element))
        underlyingCollection.Add(element);
}

public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    // todo; weak references
    var underlyingCollection = (ObservableCollection<int>)value;
    var lookup = underlyingCollection.ToLookup(x => x);

    var presentableCollection = new ObservableCollection<Wrap>();
    foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, 400))
    {
        var damnLambdaYuNoCaptureByValue = i;
        var wrap = new Wrap { IsChecked = lookup.Contains(i)};
        wrap.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) =>
            {
                if(args.PropertyName == "IsChecked")
                    UpdateUnderlyingCollection(
                       underlyingCollection, 
                       damnLambdaYuNoCaptureByValue, 
                       wrap.IsChecked);
            };

        presentableCollection.Add(wrap);
    }

    return presentableCollection;
}
```

Comment: I think, before the last edit, my question was oversimplified =) I had omitted that the `ObservableCollection` is in fact the property of an object - it appeared as if I declared it in code-behind as a member of the same class as the one containing the `ListBox`. Your answer is in fact correct for the oversimplified case, but it doesn't look to me like it applies to the now corrected form of the problem. My bad.

Comment: Well, it kind of does. Create a new VM: GridViewModel(wrapper class), fill ObservableCollection<GridViewModel> in code behind and then you can track changes of IsChecked through PropertyChanged event on GridViewModel & update the ObservbaleCollection<int> as you wish. Note I've added "Converter" to demonstrate that, but this is very hackish imo - you should be able to solve it without converters using similiar principles. Ps you want to avoid Converter because otherwise you will lose notifications from ObservableCollection and the collections won't be synchronized anymore.