# Binding checkboxes states to a BitArray in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

In the process of trying to learn WFP, I have taken the task of porting some old Winform apps into WPF and trying to stick to a MVVM model.

In the Winform app, I have a set of checkboxes that change the state of a BitArray, which in turns gets sent over TCP. Simple Stuff.

How would I do this in WPF and databinding?  How can i bind a specific checkbox to a specific bit in the BitArray?  All the examples i have found of this databind to single boolean property in VM.

EDIT:

I found the solution here by using an ObservableCollection>:

[How to bind an ObservableCollection<bool> to a Listbox of Checkboxes in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17810092/how-to-bind-an-observablecollectionbool-to-a-listbox-of-checkboxes-in-wpf)

What i don't understand is what is the purpose of:

```
public static implicit operator Wrapper<T>(T value)
{
    return new Wrapper<T> { value = value };
}
public static implicit operator T(Wrapper<T> wrapper)
{
    return wrapper.value;
}
```

Inside the wrapper class, can someone explain what this does and why its needed?

Comment: Use a Binding Converter and let the ConverterParameter property of the Binding determine which bit to get or set.

Comment: That code that you found defines conversions between the generic wrapper `Type`, and the `Type` that it wraps.  It allows you to implicitly cast one to the other, and back, as if they were the same type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The benefit of using MVVM is that you can taylor view models to suite your needs.

1. Create an Item class to track the status of each bit in the array.
2. Create a MVVM view model with an observable collection of your Item object
3. Databind your view model in code behind
4. Decorate your xaml with binding info

That's it! Enjoy!

[See an Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DinVx.png)

[Download a Full Example on GitHub](https://github.com/alac0m/DataBindingBitArray)

C#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;

namespace DataBindingBitArray
{

    /// <summary>
    /// 1. Create an Item class to track the status of each bit in the array. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <seealso cref="System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged" />
    public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public int BitArrayIndex { get; set; }
        public BitArray ParentBitArray { get; set; }

        private bool isChecked;
        public Item(int bitArrayIndex, bool isChecked, BitArray parentBitArray)
        {
            this.BitArrayIndex = bitArrayIndex;
            this.isChecked = isChecked;
            this.ParentBitArray = parentBitArray;
        }
        public bool IsChecked
        {
            get => isChecked;
            set
            {
                if (ParentBitArray != null)
                {
                    ParentBitArray[BitArrayIndex] = isChecked = value;

                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsChecked));
                }
            }
        }
        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 2. Create a MVVM view model with an observable collection of your Item object
    /// </summary>
    /// <seealso cref="System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged" />
    public class BitArrayViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private readonly BitArray bitArray;
        private ObservableCollection<Item> items;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public ObservableCollection<Item> Items
        {
            get => items;
            set
            {
                items = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Items));
            }
        }
        public BitArrayViewModel(BitArray bitArray)
        {
            this.bitArray = bitArray;

            var query = this
                .bitArray
                .Cast<bool>()
                .Select((s, i) => new Item(i, s, this.bitArray));

            this.Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>(query);
        }

        public int CountOnBits()
        {
            return this.bitArray.Cast<bool>().Count(s => s);
        }
        public int CountOffBits()
        {
            return this.bitArray.Cast<bool>().Count(s => !s);
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 3 . Databind your view model in code behind
    /// </summary>
    /// <seealso cref="System.Windows.Window" />
    /// <seealso cref="System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector" />
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public BitArrayViewModel ViewModel;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = ViewModel = new BitArrayViewModel(new BitArray(100));

            MessageBox.Show($"You have {ViewModel.CountOnBits()} on bits and {ViewModel.CountOffBits()} off bits");
        }

        private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"You have {ViewModel.CountOnBits()} on bits and {ViewModel.CountOffBits()} off bits");
        }
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="DataBindingBitArray.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataBindingBitArray"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Height="360" Width="250">
    <StackPanel Height="300" Margin="10">
        <Label Height="40"  Margin="5" FontSize="18">Binding to Bit Array</Label>
        <ScrollViewer Height="200">
            <ItemsControl  Margin="5" x:Name="ItemsControl1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" Content ="{Binding Path=BitArrayIndex }"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <Button Height="40" Margin="5" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" Content="Show BitArray Status"></Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Hello. Correct the INotifyPropertyChange isn't need on the ViewModel and can be omitted. The Item class tracks the bit index and state and checking the box changes the state which updates the bit array at the index the item represents.

Comment: I see. Just one last thing, I see the DataContext is to a BitArrayViewModel object which doesn't have the IsChecked Property, how is the Binding able to access the IsChecked Property from the Item class? Dont you have to go down BitArrayViewModel.Item.IsChecked? Or is just how XAML works?  Thanks for all the help tho, learning a lot!

Comment: The Binding of the ViewModel Items is applied to the containing ItemsControl. The IsChecked binding property is applied to each checkbox at the time the checkbox becomes databound. So you are correct in seeing it that way 
BitArrayViewModel
-- Items
----Item
--------IsChecked